# Javascript: Image object doesn't seem to load image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create image objects, one for each of my .png game assets. The `makeImage()` image maker does create the right object, and it does have the right path as its `.src`property, but it doesn't load the image. `img.isReady` remains `false`.

I'm a beginner at both javascript and coding, and I wonder if there's some behavior of functions or objects I'm overlooking.

```
var assets = {};

function makeImage(path) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.isReady = false;
    img.onload = function () {
        img.isReady = true;
    };
    img.src = path;
    return img;
}

assets.tileset = makeImage('images/tileset.png');
```

Comment: How and when do you check the `isReady` property? Any errors in you browser's developer console?

Comment: `isReady` I'm gonna be using later, when rendering. I don't use the developer console, but I just tried it and nothing stood out. Only what seems to be an unrelated comment on `« window.controllers »` being obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anjrLy40/1/

The issue is that you're returning the image `img` before the image loads, which is an asyncronous process. You should nest the return within the `onload` function. Try this:

```
function createImg( path, nodeID ) { 

    var img = new Image(),
        isLoaded = false;

    img.onload = function() {

        document.getElementById( nodeID ).appendChild( img );

        isLoaded = true;

        alert(isLoaded);
    };

    img.src = path;
};
```

The function is created and attached to the img `object` and is run once you set the `path` and that process completes. You will see the `src` set before the function is created in some people's codes, but that isn't the preferred method.

**Reference**: http://fragged.org/preloading-images-using-javascript-the-right-way-and-without-frameworks_744.html

Comment: This solved it. Thanks a lot. Could you elaborate on the asynchronous process? What makes setting a path to a source image different from other values?

Comment: JavaScript is a single threaded language. Loading an image is done by the browser anytime you set a `src` even if the image is not attached to the DOM. This is sometimes referred to as "lazy loading". So when you set the image source, although you're just attaching a `string` to the object, the browser is actually loading the image itself, which can take some time depending on the size of the image. Thus the browser does this asynchronously, to allow other processes to run at the same time. You should look into ajax, and promises. They will prove very helpful I think, cheers!